# Image use tracking possible?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have some images on my site that I made, just some `.gif` and `.jpg`.

Is it possible to find out if someone is stealing my images and using them on their own website in `<img src="">`?

How can I find the guy’s website that is stealing my images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest to put something like not direct path to the image but `src="/ImageProvider.php?imgId=12345"`. In that page/control you'll be able to revise, which host requested the image.

Comment: Please could you clarify.  Do you mean do a header redirect to the image?

Comment: +1 this works when people use the url you have poublished your image but wont actually stop someone right clicking the image and saving it to their machine for later use on their own site.  Not sure how to resolve that issue.

Comment: I mean in each place where the image is shown put <img src="/ImageProvider.php?imgId=12345"> or <img src="/ImageProvider.php?imgId=myimage.jpg">.

Comment: @Mauro That issue is resolved with watermarks :). By the way, logic for placing watermarks also can be placed in ImageProvider, but that can cause additional server overhead, so preprocessing is better.

Comment: I can see the power of this method. Thanks.  I know how to check host using $_SERVER I think so will be good!  cool.  I will use this method above + watermarking

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Referer:` header for that. It's not the most reliable method, since only a percentage of browsers actually sends it. But it's sufficient for detection. It would normally be empty or contain your websites URL at best. As soon as another domain is referenced, you can block and log it.

A common method is using mod_rewrite for such purposes in the image directory.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}  ^(.+)$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}  !^http://www.yourdomain.com/  [NC]
RewriteRule (.+)   /block_and_log.php?img=$1&domain=%1     [L]
```

Comment: Once I block his website, can he just remove the header being sent and therefore the block will not work anymore?

Comment: No. The browsers of users do. The website has no influence on whether that header is sent.

Comment: @alex: Cool. Did not really test the snippet. :}

Answer (score 1):

You can check the referrer information in the [HTTP request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer). You can disable such request with mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !yoursite.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* /accesspage.html [L]
```

But if you want to track who is using it then you will have to use an intermediate script to parse the referrer information.